# Timeline - loop through all dates between first and last given and add date to column if not found

Tags: excel, loops, date

what I have in columns A, B, C:

Date Hours Name  
 01/03/2016 8,0 John  
 02/03/2016 8,0 John  
 08/03/2016 7,5 John  
 08/03/2016 2,0 Charles 
 08/03/2016 2,0 William 
 10/03/2016 3,5 Charles  
 11/03/2016 3,7 Charles  
 14/03/2016 2,2 Charles  
 15/03/2016 8,0 John  
 16/03/2016 8,0 John

what I want in column A, B, C in another sheet:

Date Hours Name  
 01/03/2016 8,0 John  
 02/03/2016 8,0 John  
 03/03/2016 0,0 -  
 04/03/2016 0,0 -  
 05/03/2016 0,0 -  
 06/03/2016 0,0 -  
 07/03/2016 0,0 -  
 08/03/2016 7,5 John  
 08/03/2016 2,0 Charles 
 08/03/2016 2,0 William 
 09/03/2016 0,0 -  
 10/03/2016 3,5 Charles  
 11/03/2016 3,7 Charles  
 12/03/2016 0,0 -  
 13/03/2016 0,0 -  
 14/03/2016 2,2 Charles  
 15/03/2016 8,0 John  
 16/03/2016 8,0 John

It has to work with any given dates, hours and names!

Please help I really need this!

```
Sub proj0()

Dim lRow As Long

Dim Data1, Data2 As Date
Dim C1, C2 As String

Folha11.Select

    Columns("a:c").Select
    Selection.Copy

  Folha13.Select

    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Cells.Select
    Selection.Sort _
        Key1:=Range("a2"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
        key2:=Range("c2"), Order2:=xlAscending, _
        Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, _
        MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

    lRow = 2

    Do While (Cells(lRow, 1) <> "")


        C1 = Cells(lRow, "c")
        C2 = Cells(lRow + 1, "c")

        Data1 = Cells(lRow, "a")
        Data2 = Cells(lRow + 1, "a")


        If (Data2 - Data1 > 1) Then
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown

       Cells(lRow + 1, "a").Value = Data1 + 1
        Cells(lRow + 1, "b").Value = 0
        Cells(lRow + 1, "c").Value = "-"
           Else
            lRow = lRow + 1
        End If
    Loop
 Range("a:c").Columns.AutoFit
 Folha13.Select
```

I believe i'm close but cant figure the insert part

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is not a code for me service. If you have code please include it in your original post. We will help resolve specific problems with existing code.

Comment: i dont know how to code this, i need help for that

Comment: Loop backwards testing whether date is one less then the one above if not add line above with data.  Search those key words on google and try the macro recorder.  Then when you have some code that just is not working then come back.  Or you can pay someone to do it. www.freelancer.com

Comment: I understand the concept of looping for the next date and add line but i just can't code it in VBA excel, I'm new to programming. I don't know what to do, been trying for weeks. I am desperate and I need help from an expert. I can't find similar stuff in the internet or books.

Comment: "I can't find similar stuff in the internet...", what have you tried to search for? Loops in VBA are done all the time, [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20loop%20in%20vba) alone has a ton of info (and obvioulsy [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=loop+vba) does too). Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I've tried everything i can imagine with the keywords: date, loop, timeline, insert row. calendar. Well, I'm stuck in everything. For start, I can't even make a loop from the start date to the end date of a list because i never know the start or end dates of the list!

Comment: I'm having trouble in the part where i have to insert line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what you suggest:

```
Sub timeline()

Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ts As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet15") 'Change to your Output Sheet
Set ts = Sheets("Sheet14") 'Change to your data sheet

With ws
    i = ts.Range("A" & ts.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ts.Range("A1:C" & i).Copy .Range("A1")
    .Range("A1:C" & i).Sort Key1:=.Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
        key2:=.Range("C2"), Order2:=xlAscending, _
        Header:=xlYes
    Do Until i = 2
        If .Cells(i, 1).Value2 = .Cells(i - 1, 1).Value2 Or .Cells(i, 1).Value2 = .Cells(i - 1, 1).Value2 + 1 Then
            i = i - 1
        Else
            .Rows(i).Insert
            .Cells(i, 1).Value = .Cells(i + 1, 1).Value2 - 1
            .Cells(i, 2).Value = 0#
            .Cells(i, 3).Value = "--"
        End If
    Loop
End With

End Sub
```

Sheet14 Before:

[image]

Sheet15 After:

[image]

Comment: Scott Craner, I'm having an error in the if line. My Office is in Portuguese and I don't know if that is the reason or not. I changed a bit in the Set part to match my sheets but dont know if it is the cause. I'm investigating it. Is there any way you can put the excel available for download?

Comment: it worked thank you a lot!
My bad,I switched the 2 sheet names and it was the cause of the error!

Comment: @carlos_cs Parabens! Estou feliz que es facendo.