# Timeline - fill sheet with the missing dates between given interval

Tags: excel, loops, date, timeline, vba

I have the following Excel problem:

I currently have this in sheet1 columns A,B,C:

Date Time Worker
 04/04/2016 4,5 John
 05/04/2016 2 John
 06/04/2016 6,5 John
 07/04/2016 0 --
 08/04/2016 0,5 Charles
 08/04/2016 2 John
 08/04/2016 0,5 William
 09/04/2016 0 --
 10/04/2016 0 --
 11/04/2016 9 John
 11/04/2016 3,75 William

I also have in sheet 3: 
The Creation date of Project In cell E1 : 28/03/2016
The Actual start of Project In cell F1: 29/03/2016
The Today date In cell G1 (let's consider today date is the one i show next): 13/04/2016

What I want in sheet2:

Choose the earliest date between Creation and Actual start of Project, which in this case is 28/03/2016
Then add the missing dates with 0 Time and -- Worker until it reaches the Today date.
It should look like this after all done:

Date Time Worker
 28/03/2016 0 --
 29/03/2016 0 --
 30/03/2016 0 --
 31/03/2016 0 --
 01/04/2016 0 --
 02/04/2016 0 --
 03/04/2016 0 --
 04/04/2016 4,5 John
 05/04/2016 2 John
 06/04/2016 6,5 John
 07/04/2016 0 --
 08/04/2016 0,5 Charles
 08/04/2016 2 John
 08/04/2016 0,5 William
 09/04/2016 0 --
 10/04/2016 0 --
 11/04/2016 9 John
 11/04/2016 3,75 William
 12/04/2016 0 --
 13/04/2016 0 --

It is the continuation of a problem i had but only detected now:
[Timeline - loop through all dates between first and last given and add date to column if not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36984494/timeline-loop-through-all-dates-between-first-and-last-given-and-add-date-to-c)
Looking for a excel-vba macro solution because i believe it's the only way to do it.
I'm new to VBA and stuck with this problem and all the help means a lot to me!

Edited to say this: The cells where the dates of the creation, actual start of project and today are don't really matter, could be in any sheet. Just said that for exemple purpose. Hope the link provided can help you help me!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the same solution proposed by @ScottCraner, just changing a few lines

```
Sub timeline()

Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ts As Worksheet
Dim startDate as Date

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet15") 'Change to your Output Sheet
Set ts = Sheets("Sheet14") 'Change to your data sheet

' get the earliest day
startDate = cdate(application.WorksheetFunction.Min(cdate(ts.range("E1")),cdate(ts.range("E2"))))

With ws
    i = ts.Range("A" & ts.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ts.Range("A1:C" & i).Copy .Range("A1")
    .Range("A1:C" & i).Sort Key1:=.Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
        key2:=.Range("C2"), Order2:=xlAscending, _
        Header:=xlYes
    Do Until .cells(i,1).value2 = startDate ' fill all dates 'til startDate
        If .Cells(i, 1).Value2 = .Cells(i - 1, 1).Value2 Or .Cells(i, 1).Value2 = .Cells(i - 1, 1).Value2 + 1 Then
            i = i - 1
        Else
            .Rows(i).Insert
            .Cells(i, 1).Value = .Cells(i + 1, 1).Value2 - 1
            .Cells(i, 2).Value = 0#
            .Cells(i, 3).Value = "--"
        End If
    Loop
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I get na error 13 type mismatch when i=2. Also, Where did you use the "insertdate" that you defined above? The dates i need before 04/04/2016 and after 11/04/2016 are still missing. The loop isn't even starting in the today date. I believe the answer is not much different from the @ScottCraner code but I have no clue what to change.

Comment: Hi @carlos_cs, the difference is that with modification (commented) the sub will run until the date 'startDate'.
I fix the mismatch error and removed the insertDate (i just forgot in the code). Hope help you now. 
P.S.: Você é brasileiro? rs...

Comment: Hi @Kellsens sou português. The problem with your code is that the loop doesn't find in the sheet1 the lines with today and end dates. The code must have a step before the loop: It should find if the start and today date already exist in sheet1, and if they don't then add them to the top and bottom respectively. Then i guess the loop should work.

Comment: Prazer @carlos_cs.
So, I'm guessing the 'ts' is your worksheet with the data and dates. You can change the worksheet referenced to the sheet where the dates are.

Comment: Hey @Kellsens, I changed your code a bit like I just wrote and now it does what I wanted!! Can you review it? The format around todaydate seems weird. Also, If you or someone can optimise it, it would be great!

Answer (score 0):

This answer worked for me. I used @kellsens code a bit and got the answer myself!

```
Sub macro6()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ts As Worksheet
Dim fs As Worksheet
Dim startDate As Date
Dim todaydate As Date

Folha13.Select

Set ws = Sheets("sheet1") 'Change to your Output Sheet
Set ts = Sheets("sheet2") 'Change to your data sheet
Set fs = Sheets("sheet3") 'Change to your data sheet
sheet2.Range("a1:c250").ClearContents

' get the earliest day
startDate = CDate(Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(CDate(fs.Range("b6")), CDate(fs.Range("b7"))))
todaydate = CDate(fs.Range("b10"))
With ws
    i = ts.Range("A" & ts.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ts.Range("A1:C" & i).Copy .Range("A1")
    .Range("A1:C" & i).Sort Key1:=.Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
        key2:=.Range("C2"), Order2:=xlAscending, _
        Header:=xlYes

        i = 2
        If .Cells(i, 1).Value2 <> startDate Then
            .Rows(i).Insert
            .Cells(i, 1).Value = startDate
            .Cells(i, 2).Value = 0#
            .Cells(i, 3).Value = "--"

     End If

     i = ts.Range("A" & ts.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
           If .Cells(i, 1).Value2 <> todaydate Then
            .Rows(i + 1).Insert
            .Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = todaydate
            .Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = 0#
            .Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = "--"

     End If

      i = ts.Range("A" & ts.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 2

    Do Until .Cells(i, 1).Value2 = startDate ' fill all dates 'til startDate


          If .Cells(i, 1).Value2 = .Cells(i - 1, 1).Value2 Or .Cells(i, 1).Value2 = .Cells(i - 1, 1).Value2 + 1 Then
            i = i - 1
        Else
            .Rows(i).Insert
            .Cells(i, 1).Value = .Cells(i + 1, 1).Value2 - 1
            .Cells(i, 2).Value = 0#
            .Cells(i, 3).Value = "--"
        End If
  Loop

End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```